# Transactions in Google api client (Python)

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I need to manage multiple calls to Google api client python services as a single transaction (i.e. creating or updating two folders). Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Please explain what is the use case. Why can't you make 2 consecutive or parallel requests?

Comment: When handling a http get i need to create a bunch of folders OR return 500. A partial result is not allowed.

Comment: Well, then catch the exception and retry/undo/inform. Read https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/batch for a way to make batch requests, but AFAIK it will not provide a backoff mechanism (https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors)